# How Can I Lock Folders On Specific Areas?

Tags: directory, desktop-environments

In Windows, folders open on the same spot as where they were when you shut them down.

For example if I have a folder with pictures in and I open it, it opens on the far right side of the screen in Ubuntu. If I want the folder on the left side of the screen or some other place I must move the folder manually and drag it to the left side.

In Windows I never had to do this since the last place was automatically saved, so that next time I open the directory, it would open on that exact same spot as where it was when it got closed.

If you have a picture as a background on desktop, you may not want to cover the view of it with 5 folders all over the screen. Then you may want the folders to be out of sight.

Shortly explained: I would like directories to open in the specific area where it was when it got shut down.

**P.S.** With Windows i mean the operatingsystem from Microsoft!

[image: Where Folder Open Up]

[image: Where I Want The Folder To Open Up]

Comment: Do you mean icons, windows, what?

Comment: No i mean what i said, folders. Directory.

Comment: Even after your edit it is still a bit unclear. Can you please provide a screenshot of what happens on Windows and what happens on Ubuntu so we can better understand the question?

Comment: Can't be more specific then this so i hope you guys understand now!

Answer (score 0):

you can use gnome tweak tool.
in window setting turn off ''centre new window''.[image]